# UNION unexpected results?

Tags: mysql, sql, union

Let's say we have:

table 1

```
a (int) | b (int)
--------|--------
1       | 4
2       | 4
```

table 2

```
c (text)   d (text) 
---------|---------
hoi      | hi
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM table2
```

yields

```
a     | b 
------|--------
1     | 4
2     | 4
hoi   | hi
```

At least, from the query I just ran on mysql

I'd expect `(1, 4, NULL, NULL)`. Why doesn't this give an error?

Comment: MySQL has always been unpredictable.  Pretty sure if you run it in SQL Server or Oracle, it won't even run.

Comment: Returning NULL instead of the varchar values would be even more wrong - why would you expect it to return `NULL`?

Comment: In MySQL a UNION does not seem to care about the values of the columns being union-ed. It ignores the column names of the second query and uses that of the first. It also will give the datatype of whatever all of the union-ed values will fit in. This is one of many reasons I recommend PostgreSQL over MySQL for a free open source db. MySQL is far too unpredictable and allows many things that it should not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNION` just appends the rows of one query to the rows of the other. As long as the two queries return the same number of columns, there's no error. The column names always come from the fist query. If the datatypes are different, it finds a common type that they can all be converted to; in your example, it converts the `int` columns to `text` (MySQL is loose about this, some other databases require that you use explicit `CAST()` calls to get everything to the same type).

Since your queries each return two columns, the result contains two columns, using the column names from `table1`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment.

I just tested this on MySQL 8.0 and SQLite and it returns:

```
a   b
1   4
2   4
hoi hi
```

I find this surprising.  I would expect the columns to be given an integer type and for there to be either a type conversion error or `0` for the third row.  Well, actually the SQLite results isn't that strange, because types are much more fungible in SQLite.

SQL Server and Postgres give errors that I would expect -- type conversion errors that cause the query to fail.

Comment: MySQL has never been known to be strict on data type checking - apparently it tries to avoid errors as much as possible even if that means returning questionable results

Comment: MySQL was clearly designed by people who like scripting languages like PHP and JavaScript, which also convert types automatically.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I thought the standard rule was to pick the types (along with the names) from the first subquery.  So, I would expect `0` because the strings are converted to numbers.  My thought process is clearly wrong.  It seems to be picking the types differently for `union` than it would for expressions with combined types.

Comment: Well, I think (not 100% sure) the standard rule is: the first query defines the data types of the columns. The data types of the columns of the other queries must be "compatible". So if the first query returns integer, all others have to return something that can be cast to an integer. If the first query returns `varchar` the all others have to return something that can be cast to a varchar

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . That is my understanding as well.  However, MySQL and SQLite appears to be saying "to heck with the first subquery, a string anywhere is a string everywhere!"